# とも means and usage in this context

Tags: particles

傘もなくて、二人**とも**ずぶ濡れ状態だ

Does it relate to the first も
Also is it common to add an adjective before 状態 do describe appearances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 傘もなくて、二人ともずぶ濡れ状態だ

means, "without an umbrella, both of us got completely drenched."

The とも in 二人とも emphasizes the idea of "the two of us". The も is not tied to the preceding one. As commented, とも is a word unto itself meaning "together" or "both" appended to the word for which the meaning applies.

Using  状態 is not uncommon at all.  This is a completely normal sounding sentence. There is no adjective.  濡れ is a noun formed off of the verb ぬれる which means to get wet.  状態 is often appended to nouns to describe a certain state of affairs.  I would memorize these as you encounter them.

Comment: it's worth noting that とも isn't a particle and has a kanji 共